# Service workers in React Native/ Ionic/ Apache Cordova

Tags: react-native, cordova, ionic-framework, service-worker

Is it possible to register a service worker from a mobile app made with a js framework like react-native or ionic and receive push notifications ?

Comment: window.navigator.serviceWorker is undefined

Comment: How would i help u if I couldn't see ur code or provide more details?